# Elegant way to calculate fraction of two cummulated values in React

Tags: reactjs

I am still not very fluent in React, and I am supposed to expand existing code. Inside a `render()` function, I found the following:

```
const myStyle = { float: "right", color: "red"} as React.CSSProperties;

<myComponent myProperty={
   () => {
            return <div style={myStyle}>
               {(((this.props.myData)) ? "Total var1: ".concat(
                   this.props.myData.reduce(function (prev, cur) { 
                      return prev + cur.VarOne;}).toString(), 
                   " Total var2: ",
                   this.props.myData.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
                     return prev + cur.VarTwo;}).toString(),
                   " var1/var2: TBD"
                  ) : null )}  </div>
          }
    }
/>
```

All this works without issues. However, **I now want to calculate the fraction `var1/ var2`**, and output that as well. How do I do that without sweeping again with a `.reduce()` over all records?

Any help is appreciated! I don't even know what to search for, that's why I am bothering all of you.

#### Background info

`myData` seems to be (a nested) list of custom defined records:

```
export interface DataViewTableProps {
    selectedDate: any,
    myData: Interfaces.myDataEntry[],
}

export interface myDataEntry{
    PositionId: number,
    PositionName: string,
    Value: number,
    children: myDataEntry[],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're iterating over the same array twice, you could use a forEach to do all of your computations at once:

```
const myData = this.props.myData;
let first = 0;
let second = 0;
myData.forEach(entry => {
   first += entry.VarOne;
   second += entry.VarTwo;
});

const tbd = first / second;
```

Something that will make your React code cleaner is extracting all of your computations outside of the `return` area of the `render` function.

So instead of doing this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{ // compute the output here} 
        </div>
    )
}
```

It's better to do this:

```
render() {
    const myOutput = //  compute the output here  
    return (
        <div>{myOutput} </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints, Ana, in particular about clean code.